# Subset relation between two polyhedral cones

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra, convex-cone

Suppose we are given two vectors $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $m \leq n$ vectors $a_1, \dotsc, a_m \in\mathbb{R}^n$ with

- $ a_1, \dotsc, a_m \notin \text{cone}\, (b_1,b_2) $
- $ \text{cone}(a_1, \dotsc, a_m) \cap \text{cone}\, (b_1,b_2) \neq \emptyset$

Is the following statement true or false?

- $ \text{cone}\, (b_1,b_2) \subseteq  \text{cone}(a_1, \dotsc, a_m) $

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: So far, I could only verify the claim for $n=2$. But even there, I have not yet managed to write it down nicely (neither directly nor by contradiction). I think what I'm lacking is a way to apply the knowledge about existence of element $x\in$ cone$(b_1,b_2) \cap$ cone$(a_1,\dotsc, a_m)$ to say something about all other elements in cone$(b_1,b_2)$